# Get changed fields by Spring Auditing

Tags: spring, spring-orm

Can I somehow use spring Auditing to get list changed fields of entity and their old, new values?

I was trying to get the list of updated fields for entity and their old and new values for logs. I used getDeclaredFields to compare old entity and new entity before updating, and it works. But still was wondering if there are some standart and simplier ways of solution. 
I am using spring and hibernate to manage my entities. 
After researching I found that there can be used hibernate session for my purposes, by adding listener on updating event and using getDirtyProperties from event. But as I understood it requires hibernate transaction manager, and I am already using JpaTransactionManager and can not change it.

Then I was told about this spring audit feature
http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.auditing
and the question is if it can provide something like getDirtyProperties? Or maybe there are another ways of solution? Because creating new tables is unwanted, and if I get it right, spring auditing requires storage audit data in data base.

Comment: What do you mean by Spring auditing? Also, do you need to keep the history for each audited field?

Comment: Updated post with details. Need to find out if spring has a tool to get changed fields for object. The history for each audited field is unwanted, can this be somehow avoided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's actually nothing in Spring's [Auditable](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Auditable.html) that requires it be stored in the database, but it also doesn't include the level of detail you're looking for as far as which fields changed. [Hibernate Envers](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/envers/3.6/reference/en-US/html/) does that, but I believe it can only store audit records in the database. You might be able to use it as a starting point, though.